# Threading C# UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

This may sound silly but I didn't want to hijack a question.

I recently read this post:

[Why a second UI thread freezes the first one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865260/why-a-second-ui-thread-freezes-the-first-one)

and after reading the solution I felt that I was very weak with threading/ui/c#.  Does anyone know where I can read more about this and more specifically understand the terminology.  I'm looking for something hands on if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is suggested that the Threading by [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) is the best book available. But i do not think that the threading in WPF is quite different than explained by Albahari. Even in case of handling UI threads.

Comment: does this tutorial also help define the terms as well?  such as marshaling?

Comment: Quick search for the word marshal in his book leads to few chapters. So i guess yes. I am sorry, i have not gone through it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Joe Albahari's ebook is the best free resource I know of ( he actually knows what he's talking about ), so I would start there.

However, Joe Duffy's book ( Concurrent Programming on Windows ) has much more detail - 1,000 pages worth! It's mandatory reading if you want to get serious.